Is there something like Shabbath in Islam?
Is there something like Sabbath in Islam?
A day when no work is allowed? Jews have that, and observe it quite strictly.
Christians have it, but place it on Sunday instead of Saturday.
As far as I know, the "holy day" in Islam is on Friday, but I don't know of any restrictions to do work on Fridays.
The closest to Sabbath I can think of is Ramadan, but as far as I understand, work is not prohibited as such, only avoided due to the stress imposed by fasting.
Is my understanding correct? If not, what am I missing?

Looks like this is a difficult question, so I try to rephrase it: is there any time or calendar date in Islam where doing work is haram?

Again, this question has been misunderstood. The question is not if Muslims observe Shabbath, whether on Saturday or on Friday or on Sunday.
Obviously NO.
The question was if there is any concept equal to Shabbath and the accepted answer is "no, except for the times of obligatory prayers", where work cannot be done because the prayer requires all attention.

@UmH No, even in your link it is really two questions. One, if Muslims observe Sabbath, and the clear and obvious answer is: no.  My question is if there is something comparable, a time where work is forbidden.

As far as I know there isn't any sort of a day were no work is allowed except around 1 hour in friday and 15 minutes * 5 = 1 hour 15 minutes every day(for 5 prayers).
So total compulsory no work per week is around (7*1:15) + 1 = 9:45 hours.
In Quran:

You are already aware of those of you who broke the Sabbath. We said to them, “Be disgraced apes!”(quran 2:65)

So breaking sabbath is a grievous sin in past.
This will lead to questions such us:

Why quran doesn't force prophet muhammed to follow it?
Why such a law once implemented by god, doesn't implemented in muslims?


It might not be obvious, but in 2:65 "those of you" is referring to the people of Israel, not to Muslims.

@RayButterworth the thing similar to sabbath for muslims is daily 5 times prayer

So the answer is: NO, but for "technical" reasons, work is not allowed, more precisely is not possible while praying.

Not really. Unlike Judaism, God doesn't really mandate worshippers to rest on a particular day.
The only real mandated "break" God commands is when He tells Muslims to leave for Friday mass:

"O believers! When the call to prayer is made on Friday, then proceed ˹diligently˺ to the remembrance of God and leave off ˹your˺ business. That is best for you, if only you knew."

Quran 62:9
God goes on to say in the following verse:

"Once the prayer is over, disperse throughout the land and seek the bounty of God. And remember God often so you may be successful."

Quran 62:10
With regards to the Sabbath, God says:

"The Sabbath was prescribed only for those people (i.e. Jews) who differed in it, and your Lord will certainly judge between them on the Day of Resurrection in those matters in which they used to differ."

Quran 16:124
